# Why does Cast<T>() fail for simple ValueTuple<string, bool?>

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

Targeting `.NET 6`. Consider this simple tuple-cast:

```cs
(string, bool) x = ("", false);
var ok = ((string, bool?))x;          // Valid!
Console.WriteLine(ok);

Enumerable.Repeat(x, 1)
   .Cast<(string, bool?)>().ToList(); // Invalid?!
```

The call to `Cast<T>()` throws:

> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast
> object of type 'System.ValueTuple2[System.String,System.Boolean]'
> to type 'System.ValueTuple2[System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]]'.

What's up with this `Cast<T>()` method? Why can't it cast the value?